# API error : Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

Tags: reactjs, frontend, fetch-api

I have an API that I pulling a bunch of different dogs from. When you login it submits your name/email into the body of the API to give access to the API. My inputs submit but i get this error as it pulls the data initially.

Here is the ERROR:

```
dataAuthUsage.js?t=1688388408867:26 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'HTMLInputElement'
    |     property '__reactFiber$y331mfbge1' -> object with constructor 'FiberNode'
    --- property 'stateNode' closes the circle
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
    at authLogin (dataAuthUsage.js?t=1688388408867:26:16)
    at loginSubmit (Login.jsx?t=1688390323610:34:5)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback2 (react-dom.development.js:4164:14)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:16)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:31)
    at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (react-dom.development.js:4291:25)
    at executeDispatch (react-dom.development.js:9041:3)
    at processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder (react-dom.development.js:9073:7)
    at processDispatchQueue (react-dom.development.js:9086:5)
```

Here is my code for the API to start and the place it points to is the `body: JSON.stringify(payload)`:

```js
export const authLogin = async (name, email) => {
  const payload = {
    name: name,
    email: email,
  };
  return fetch(Fetch_Api + "/auth/login", {
    ...Set_Options,
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify(payload),
  })
    .then((response) => {
      if (response.ok) {
        return response;
      }
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      throw e;
    });
};
```

Here is my login in page that suppose to submit my authorization to the API:

```js
const name = useRef("");
const email = useRef("");

const loginSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    authLogin(name, email);
  

    if (name.current.value === "" || email.current.value === "") {
      alert("Name and Email Required");
    } else {
      setUser((user) => [
        {
          userName: name.current.value,
          userEmail: email.current.value,
        },
      ]);

      setLoggedIn(true);
      navigate("/home");
    }
  };
  
  
  <form>
        <h3> Name</h3>
        <input placeholder="Full Name..." ref={name} type="name" required />
        <br />

        <h3>Email</h3>
        <input placeholder="Email..." ref={email} type="email" required />
        <br />
        <button onClick={loginSubmit}>Login</button>
      </form>
```